# JMeter JavaScript global scope in BSF Assertion

Tags: javascript, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, global-scope

I'm wanting to assert against JSON responses without using plugins on JMeter's BSF Assertions. For this purpose, I've created a simple set of util functions that cover my current use case: https://gist.github.com/formigone/410778976e01e0be3f572b43f331589b

### My Question

What's a way to include my mini library globally within JMeter, so any BSF Assertion can have access to them?

I've tried adding the lib to a BSF PreProcessor in various scopes, but can't get it to work. I've tried putting it in a vars, but that only works in some of the threads.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I can think of is converting your utility code into [Beanshell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeanShell).

If you want to keep your JavaScript intact there is a possibility to call JavaScript code from Beanshell test elements like:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;

ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
result = engine.eval("your JavaScript here");
```

Beanshell implementation in JMeter provides `bsh.shared` namespace which is globally available across all Thread Groups.

References:

- [Sharing Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_variables)
- [Java Scripting Programmer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/)
- [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)

Comment: But then how will the various individual JavaScript assertions access the lib?